# .htaccess rewrite rule exception

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a small question.
I have build a system and it is using a .htaccess to direct the traffic to the correct locations.

Now I have the following .htaccess data

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    core/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) core/$1    [L]
///###  (does not work.. this is a problem) RewriteRule    (.*) app/template/ !page    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

The problem is actually that when I want to show a .css file located in **/app/templates** it also redirects to **/core/**

I tried to make an exception. However that does not really seem to work at my method.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    core/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) core/$1    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/template/ !page    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

This .htaccess gives a 500 error.
Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? And how I can make the exception work for the template directory?

TIAD!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteRule ^$ core/ [L]

   # If the request is not for a valid directory
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   # If the request is not for a valid file
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
   RewriteRule (.*) core/$1 [L]

 </IfModule>
```

Comment: can you please give details what the `!-d` does in this line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` ?

Comment: I have already included in my comments above that line i.e. it checks **If the request is not for a valid directory**

Comment: I was trying to understand the structure of flag? itself - i.e. - is it a flag? that doesnt have `[..]` around it?

Comment: No it is not a flag. `-d` checks for directory